# Formatting footnotes for html output via xslt doesn't handle normalize-space and introduces extra whitespace

Tags: html, xslt

I have an issue with extra whitespace in my html output from xml that I'm trying to solve and nothing seems to actually do it.

I have the following xml block with a number of mixed-content elements (I apologize for the messiness of this block, but it's mixed-content and so whitespace is germane to the question):

```
        <surface xml:id="p.1" n="panel"> 
            <zone n="EETS.T.30">
                <line n="l.1">
                    <damage n="legible"><hi>O</hi> ih<ex>es</ex>u</damage>
                    <damage n="illegible"> m</damage>ercy wyth <damage n="legible"
                    >sup</damage>port of thy<ex>n</ex> gr<damage n="legible">ace</damage>
                </line>
                <line n="l.2"> f<damage n="legible">or th</damage>y<ex>n</ex> me<damage
                        n="illegible">ke</damage>
                    <note anchored="true" place="bottom" n="explanatory">A big ol' note</note> passio<ex>u</ex>n reme<ex>m</ex>b<damage
                        n="legible">r</damage>e our<ex>e</ex> co<ex>m</ex>pleynt </line>
                <line n="l.3"> duryng our<ex>e</ex> lyf w<ex>ith</ex> m<damage n="illegible"
                        >an</damage>y gret trespace </line>
                <line n="l.4"> by many wrong <damage n="legible">pa</damage>th wher<ex>e</ex> we
                    haue myswent </line>
                <line n="l.5"> we now purpose by grace influent </line>
                <line n="l.6"> calle to reme<ex>m</ex>braunce of surfetis don to the<note
                        anchored="true" place="bottom" n="informational">Another big ol' note.</note>
                </line>
                <line n="l.7">
                    <gap quantity="3" reason="illegible" unit="chars"/>
                    <gap quantity="6" reason="illegible" unit="chars"/>
                    <gap quantity="2" reason="illegible" unit="chars"/>
                    <damage n="illegible">our<ex>e</ex> laste testament</damage>
                    <note anchored="true" place="bottom" n="explanatory">This guy never shuts up, does he?</note>
                </line>
                <line n="l.8"> wyth ih<ex>es</ex>u mercy knelyng on our<ex>e</ex> kne </line>
            </zone>
        </surface>
```

I am using the following piece of code to normalize space between elements in the mixed-content  element where I don't want whitespace between them, which works great. Damage is just the example, here.

```
<xsl:template match="tei:damage[preceding-sibling::tei:damage]">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

The issue, though, is that I'm eventually rendering the page to html and I want the notes to behave as expected in html. To do this, I have code that adds superscript numbers and links for each note to the output:

```
<xsl:template match="tei:note">
    <xsl:variable name="num">
         <xsl:number count="tei:note" level="any" from="tei:surface"/>
         <xsl:value-of select="tei:surface[@xml:id]"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@n = 'explanatory'">
            <span class="footnote explanatory">
                <sup>
                    <a>
                        <xsl:attribute name="href">
                            <xsl:value-of select="concat('#fn', $num)"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="concat('fn', $num)"
                            />-ref</xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="title">link to footnote <xsl:value-of select="$num"
                            /></xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$num"/>
                    </a>
                </sup>
            </span>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="@n = 'informational'">
            <span class="footnote informational">
                <sup>
                    <a>
                        <xsl:attribute name="href">
                            <xsl:value-of select="concat('#fn', $num)"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="concat('fn', $num)"
                            />-ref</xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="title">link to footnote <xsl:value-of select="$num"
                            /></xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$num"/>
                    </a>
                </sup>
            </span>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <span class="footnote other">
                <sup>
                    <a>
                        <xsl:attribute name="href">
                            <xsl:value-of select="concat('#fn', $num)"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="concat('fn', $num)"
                            />-ref</xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="title">link to footnote <xsl:value-of select="$num"
                            /></xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$num"/>
                    </a>
                </sup>
            </span>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

This code works as expected when it's just text before the node.  But when it's something like damage it introduces whitespace that makes the resulting html have a space between the contents when it's rendered on the page.  So where I expect

```
<div class="zone col-5 col-s-5">
              <div class="line"><span class="capital">N</span>ow in the name of oure lord ihesus</div>
              <div class="line"> of right hool herte <span class="ex">&amp;</span> in our<span class="ex">e</span><span class="footnote explanatory"><sup><a href="#fn1" id="fn1-ref" title="link to footnote 1">1</a></sup></span> best entent</div>
              <div class="line"> our<span class="ex">e</span> lyf reme<span class="ex">m</span>bryng froward and vicious</div>
              <div class="line"> ay contrarye to the comaundement</div>
              <div class="line"> of crist ih<span class="ex">es</span>u now wyth avisement</div>
              <div class="line"> the lord besechi<span class="damage">ng</span> [..]<span class="footnote informational"><sup><a href="#fn2" id="fn2-ref" title="link to footnote 2">2</a></sup></span> mercy and pete</div>
              <div class="line"> our<span class="ex">e</span> youthe <span class="ex">&amp;</span> age that we have <span class="damage">mysp</span>ent</div>
              <div class="line"> wyt<span class="damage">h t</span>his woord mercy knelyng on our<span class="ex">e</span> kne<span class="footnote informational"><sup><a href="#fn3" id="fn3-ref" title="link to footnote 3">3</a></sup></span></div>
```

I'm instead getting

```
<div class="zone col-5 col-s-5">
              <div class="line">
                 <span class="capital">N</span>ow in the name of oure lord ihesus  <a href="#" onclick="compare_toggle_visibility('EETS.T.29', 'l.1', 'Testament', '')"><span class="compare">•</span></a></div>
              <div class="line"> of right hool herte
                 <span class="ex">&amp;</span> in our<span class="ex">e</span>
                 <span class="footnote explanatory"><sup><a href="#fn1" id="fn1-ref" title="link to footnote 1">1</a></sup></span> best
                 entent  </div>
              <div class="line"> our<span class="ex">e</span> lyf
                 reme<span class="ex">m</span>bryng froward and vicious  </div>
              <div class="line"> ay contrarye to the
                 comaundement  </div>
              <div class="line"> of crist ih<span class="ex">es</span>u
                 now wyth avisement  <a href="#" onclick="compare_toggle_visibility('EETS.T.29', 'l.5', 'Testament', '')"><span class="compare">•</span></a></div>
              <div class="line"> the lord besechi<span class="damage">ng</span>
                 [..]
                 <span class="footnote informational"><sup><a href="#fn2" id="fn2-ref" title="link to footnote 2">2</a></sup></span>
                 mercy and pete
                  </div>
              <div class="line"> our<span class="ex">e</span> youthe
                 <span class="ex">&amp;</span> age that we have <span class="damage">mysp</span>ent
                  </div>
              <div class="line"> wyt<span class="damage">h t</span>his woord mercy knelyng on our<span class="ex">e</span> kne<span class="footnote informational"><sup><a href="#fn3" id="fn3-ref" title="link to footnote 3">3</a></sup></span>
                  </div>
           </div>
```

How do I suppress the added carriage returns to get it to render properly? If I try the method I'm using for the damage elements it will just display the text in the note element and if I replace "." with "node()" the problem does not resolve itself.

Comment: I'm puzzled by what this is doing inside the `num` variable: `<xsl:value-of select="tei:surface[@xml:id]"/>`. I mean, surely there's no `surface` inside the `note`?

Comment: Where exactly do you see an unwanted space in the rendered HTML? The carriage returns do not have any impact.

Comment: I'm struggling to follow this, perhaps because it seems like the example you've given of input TEI isn't the source of the example output HTML?

Comment: It doesn't matter in this example, but in other files I'm using xml:id to indicate whether it's the front or back side of a page. It could probably be removed without causing a problem, to be honest.

Comment: The full xsl for this is pretty large so I tried to limit it to just the elements that are germane to my question. Most of what I left out just transform various xml elements to spans that can then be styled with css. For example, there's a template for damage, or ex that wrap them in a span with the appropriate class.  These work fine in terms of rendering it into html.

Comment: Note does not work with carriage returns because when a note element is immediately following another element a space is introduced such that the viewer sees "for thyn meke 1 passioun remembre oure compleynt" rather than the expected "for thyn meke1 passioun remembre oure compleynt." What I can't figure out is how to remove that leading space while keeping the numbering I mentioned.

Comment: (Sorry about the comment spam -- I was hitting word limits)

Comment: My point about the surface and note elements is that your template matches `note` and evaluated an XPath which implies the existence of a possible `surface` child element, but the content model of `note` does not include `surface`, which belongs rather in a `sourceDoc` or `facsimile` element.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your problem may be the white space nodes which are generated in the `when`, `otherwise`, etc clauses of your `note`-matching template. e.g.

```xml
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <span class="footnote other">
```

The `xsl:otherwise` element has a first child which is a text node consisting of a line feed and several spaces.

There are various things you could try:

```xml
        <xsl:otherwise><span class="footnote other">
```

...or

```xml
        <xsl:otherwise><!--
            --><span class="footnote other">
```

...or

```xml
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:text/><span class="footnote other">
```

...or

```xml
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:element name="span">
                <xsl:attribute name="class">footnote other</xsl:attribute>
```